# Modifying unique_ptr's target and also initializing a const unique_ptr with it

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Suppose `class Owner` has `Member member` which must also have a `const` pointer to its `const` owner. That pointer is given to `member` in `Owner`'s constructor, which accepts a pointer to the constituent `member` as an argument.

Consider `Owner`'s constructor:

```
using namespace std;

class Owner;

class Member {
friend class Owner;
private:
    // this object needs to know its owner for whatever reason
    void setOwnership(const Owner* o){
        if(owner != nullptr){
            throw logic_error("Already owned.");
        }
        owner = o;
    }
    const Owner* owner;
};

class Owner {
public:

    Owner(Member* m)
        : member(move(m))
    {
        m->setOwnership(this);
    }

    // need to define copy ctor, move ctor, copy assignment, move assignment, destructor
        // because we own member

protected:
    const Member* const member;
};
```

Now I want `unique_ptr` to handle `member`'s ownership for me, so I try

```
class Owner {
public:

    // ATTEMPT 1
    Owner(unique_ptr<Member> m)
        : member(move(m))
    {
        member->setOwnership(this); // this doesn't work because member points to a const
    }

    // ATTEMPT 2
    Owner(unique_ptr<Member> m){
        m->setOwnership(this);
        member = move(m); // this doesn't work because member is const 
    }

protected:
    const unique_ptr<const Member> member;
};
```

Both attempts at `Owner`'s constructor don't compile. How do I do this? There doesn't seem to be a reason in principle why I shouldn't be able to do it.

Do I have to sacrifice one of the `const`s just for the convenience of using `unique_ptr`?

Comment: There was a question earlier about the use of the comma operator in C++. I believe I may have just found one: `: member((m->setOwnership(this), move(m)))` I have no idea if that will work.

Comment: The details of the design smells fishy. But in any case, there are tricks with base classes you can do. The comma thing should work but risks confusing/surprising the reader, alternatively you could make a helper static member function and use `:member(help(m))`.

Comment: @Hurkyl Is it because the constructor is modifying its arguments? This is for a dynamically bottom-up constructed tree (or forest) of nodes where children need to know their parents, but we only want to keep track of the roots in the client application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegating constructor to the rescue:

```
class Owner {
public:
    Owner(std::unique_ptr<Member> m) : Owner(m, m.get()) {}

private:
    Owner(unique_ptr<Member>& m, Member* ptr) : member(std::move(m)){
        ptr->setOwnership(this);
    }

protected:
    const std::unique_ptr<const Member> member;
};
```

Comment: Note that such a `Owner` could neither be copied nor moved because, well, its `member` is now `const` and the non-`const` is lost without use of `const_cast`.

Comment: @inetknght: As in OP code, and it seems good that the class cannot be (default-)moved else member will pointer to dangling `owner`.